# Datepicker traz calendário errado depois de preencher o campo

Tags: javascript, datepicker, rails4

Acontece assim: Mum campo date, quando está vazio, ele traz o datepicker corretamente e preenche o campo no formato de banco `aaaa-mm-dd` e salva nesse formato. 
Quando vou editar, ao colocar o cursor nesse campo, ele traz um calendário diferente, com outra data. Por exemplo, se escolho 06/03/2017, ele salva 2017-03-06 e quando vou editar ele mostra um calendário de 1911. Onde estou errando? Segue o código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
        language: "pt-BR"
    });
});

...

<td> <%= f.text_field :data_vencimento_real, class: 'datepicker' %></td>
```

Comment: estou com o mesmo problema utilizando o datepicker no Django, o problema é no Javascript e não no Rails

Comment: O problema não está no salvar mas no carregar do banco de dados, onde deves converter a data para o formato devido antes de enviar para view.

Answer (score -1):

Tente inserir data inicial dessa forma.
      startDate: "01/01/1930"

e..<%= f.text_field :birth_date, placeholder: 'dd/mm/yyyy', :class =>"form-control datepicker" %>